# Averaging TIFF images in Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, tiff, average

I'm trying to average 8 TIFF images in Matlab, but I've been unable to get a proper result. If I read in the images and divide by a fixed number (the number of images read), I end up with a very dark image instead of an "average image" with even brightness. The code I used is as follows:

```
i = 0;
R = 0;
A=imread('1.tif');
B=imread('2.tif');
R = imdivide((imadd(A,B)),2);

for i = 3:8
    TEMP = imadd(R,imread(sprintf('%d.tif' ,i)));
    R = imdivide(TEMP,8);
end

imshow(R);
imwrite(R,'AVG.tif','tif');
```

Is there any way to fix this averaging scheme?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand how you are performing your averaging. You seem to be iteratively adding in a new image and then dividing by two, which does not give a true average. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average  (EDIT: see @Richante's answer )

Comment: You're right! I hadn't changed the number I was dividing by! It should be updated now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that summing the images causes overflow (Richante is correct that `imadd` uses saturating arithmetic when overflow occurs).  You need to change to a data type capable of holding the sum without loss.

e.g.

```
A = double(imread('1.tif'));

for i = 2:8
    A = A + double(imread(sprintf('%d.tif' ,i)));
end
```

...

```
R = uint8(A / 8);
```

Of course you need to convert back to whatever the original data type was.

Comment: Also, just for the sake of completeness, I used the following [example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f2-1667.html) to convert my datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

Might be better to do:

```
R = imdivide(imread('1.tif'), 8);
for i = 2:8
    R = imadd(R,imdivide(imread(sprintf('%d.tif' ,i)), 8));
end
```

This will avoid saturation, and will add them in the right way (the way use will be an average strongly weighted in favour of the image 8).

Comment: For my application, it's very important that I do not introduce any error.

Answer (score 0):

Even easier, suppose that **X** = [X1; X2; X3... X8] is an array with dimensions (rows,columns,8) in which:

```
X1 = imread('1.tif');
X1 = double(X1);
...
X = cat(3,X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8);
R = mean(X,3);
```

Where R is the average matrix.